# issue with Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

we have static file on our gitlab repository which has yaml content in below format and file naming convention is this `PROJECT_NAME-ENV_NAME-images.yaml`

```
producta:
  service1:
    image:
      repository: repo
      pullPolicy: Always
      # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
      tag: "v1.1.80"
  serviceb:
    image:
      repository: repo
      pullPolicy: Always
      # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
      tag: "v1.1.42"
productb:
  servicec:
    image:
      repository: repo
      pullPolicy: Always
      # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
      tag: "v1.1.42"
  smoke_test:
    image:
      repository: repo
      pullPolicy: Always
      # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
      tag: "2dc13f68"
  serviced:
    image:
      repository: repo
      pullPolicy: Always
      # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
      tag: "v1.1.42"
  servicee:
    image:
      repository: repo
      pullPolicy: Always
      # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
      tag: "v1.1.42"
  servicee:
    image:
      repository: repo
      pullPolicy: Always
      # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
      tag: "v0.0.9"
```

now we have input parameter defined PROJECT_NAME and ENV_NAME.
`what we are trying to do?`
we want user to enter project, env and list of products for which user need to update the tag change request.
`products` is Active Choice parameter type and it is MultiSelect.

now once user enter above input values then we want to render html input table where user will have list services and tag value for the products which user entered.
below is our groovy script which we have configured in Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter `servicesToBeUpdated`.

```
def gitlabUrl = "https://gitlab.com/group/helm-charts.git"
def gitlabCredentialsId = "XXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX-XXX"
def gitlabBranch = "v1"
def imagesYamlFile = "images/project/${params.Project}-${params.Env}-images.yaml"

withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: gitlabCredentialsId, usernameVariable: 'GITLAB_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GITLAB_PASSWORD')]) {
    sh """
        rm -rf repo
        git clone --branch ${gitlabBranch} ${gitlabUrl} repo
        cp repo/${imagesYamlFile} .
    """
}


def imagesYaml = readYaml file: imagesYamlFile
def productslist = imagesYaml.keySet()

for (product in productslist) {
  def microservices = imagesYaml[product].keySet()

  def service_list = []

  for (microservice in microservices) {
    def yamlLength = imagesYaml[product][microservice].size()

    if (yamlLength > 1 && microservice.equals("image")) {
      def tag = imagesYaml[product][microservice].tag
      def service = [:]
      service['service'] = microservice
      service['release_tag'] = tag
      service_list.add(service)
    } else if (yamlLength > 1) {
      def msImage = imagesYaml[product][microservice].keySet()

      for (mss in msImage) {
        def mssYamlLength = imagesYaml[product][microservice][mss].size()

        if (mssYamlLength > 1 && mss != "SNOWFLAKE_CONTAINER_IMAGE") {
          def tag = imagesYaml[product][microservice][mss].tag
          def service = [:]
          service['service'] = "${microservice}.${mss}"
          service['release_tag'] = tag
          service_list.add(service)
        }
      }
    } else {
      def image = imagesYaml[product][microservice].image
      def tag = image.tag
      def service = [:]
      service['service'] = microservice
      service['release_tag'] = tag
      service_list.add(service)
    }
  }

  service_tier_map[product] = service_list
}
// Get the list of products to update from the user input
def productsToUpdate = params.products.split(",")


// Loop through each product and its associated services
service_tier_map.each { selectedProduct, services ->
  // Check if the current product is in the list of products to update
  if (productsToUpdate.contains(product)) {
    def updated_services = []

    // Loop through each service and update its release tag
    services.each { service ->
      updated_services.add(service)
    }

    service_to_be_updated_map[product] = updated_services
  }
}
html_to_be_rendered = "<table><tr>"
service_to_be_updated_map.each { product, services ->
  services.each { service ->
    html_to_be_rendered = """
      ${html_to_be_rendered}
      <tr>
      <td>
      <input name=\"value\" alt=\"${service.service}\" json=\"${service.service}\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\" \">
      <label title=\"${service.service}\" class=\" \">${service.service}</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type=\"text\" class=\" \" name=\"value\" value=\"${service.release_tag}\"> </br>
      </td>
      </tr>
  """
  }
}
html_to_be_rendered = "${html_to_be_rendered}</tr></table>"
return html_to_be_rendered
```

`Issue`
when we try to build pipeline and change the value for `products` input parameter then nothing comes up under `servicesToBeUpdated` parameter on Jenkins ui.

looking for guidance on this from community.